# How to ensure that the function is exist in controller from the uri segment - Codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, controller, routes

I have a controller like `Users` and it has many functions inside the controller.If I entered the function name wrongly then the page should redirect to `404 page`.But it shows an empty page.

For example:

> http://demo.cogzidel.com/dropinn416/users/sgdfhushfv

Kindly give me some ideas to solve this, Thankx in advance

Comment: have you added url helper in autoload file?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls

Comment: Hi dhruv, thanks for your response

Comment: I have added an URL helper in autoload like following is it correct?

'$autoload['helper'] = array('common','translate','url','facebook','user','date','seasonal');'

Comment: And I have added  '$this->load->helper('url');' top of the controller

Comment: Did you override the controller/function for your 404 page? The config for that is under `application/config/routes.php` as `$route['404_override']`. What you see could possibly be your 404 page, which might be empty.

Comment: Yes @Hicro I did it like 
     ' $route['404_override']          = 'home/not_found'; '

Comment: Have you created a custom view for 404? If so, is it loading properly in `not_found` function?

Comment: Yes @Hicaro, I have created the Custom view for 404, for example, you can view this link. (http://demo.cogzidel.com/dropinn416/dropinn416/ahsdgv/aisjdfisgadf)

Comment: Trying any other random link, such as (http://demo.cogzidel.com/dropinn416/comments), the 404 page seems to be working. My best guess now is that you have an URI route set up like `$route['users/(:any)'] = 'users/index/$1';` in the `routes.php` config file.

Comment: Hi @Hicaro sorry for the late response, I have not added like you mentioned in routes.php. I have been facing such this issue in many controllers like the following - Calendar 1.cron 2.database_cron 3.message 4.neighbourhoods 5.pages 6.rss 7.statistics 8.travelling 9. trips